# How to include a PowerShell script file in a GitLab CI YAML file

Tags: powershell, gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Currently I have a large Bash script in my GitLab [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) YAML file. The example below is how I am grouping my functions so that I can use them during my CI process.

```
.test-functions: &test-functions |
   function write_one() { echo "Function 1" }
   function write_two() { echo "Function 2"}
   function write_three() { echo "Function 3"}


.plugin-nuget:
   tags:
      - test-es
      - kubernetes
   image: mygitlab-url.com:4567/containers/dotnet-sdk-2.2:latest

   script:
      - *test-functions
      - write_one
      - write_two
      - write_three
```

The example below shows how we can include a YAML file inside another one:

```
include:
   - project: MyGroup/GitlabCiPlugins/Dotnet
     file: plugin-test.yml
     ref: JayCiTest
```

I would like to do the same thing with my script. Instead of having the script in the same file as my YAML, I would like to include the file, so that my YAML has access to my script's functions. I would also like to use PowerShell instead of Bash if possible.

How can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this [link](https://www.powershell.amsterdam/2015/12/04/powershell-and-gitlab-ci-part-3/) can be helpful for executing a `powershell` script file inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Split shell scripts and GitLab CI syntax

- GitLab CI has no feature "include file content to script block".
- GitLab CI `include` feature doesn't import YAML anchors.
- GitLab CI can't concat arrays. So you cant write `before_script` in one .gitlab-ci.yml file and then use it in `before_script` in another. You can only rewrite it, not concat.

Because of all of these problems you can't easily manage your scripts; split them, organize them and do another nice developer's decomposition stuff.

There are possible workarounds. You can store your scripts somewhere else; where a gitlab runner could reach them, and then inject them to your current job environment via `source /ci-scripts/my-script.sh` in `before_script` block.

Possible locations for storing ci scripts:

1. Special docker image with all your build/test/deploy utils and ci scripts
2. The same, but dedicated build server
3. You can deploy simple web page containing your scripts and download and import then in `before_script`. Just in case, make sure nobody, except gitlab runner could access it.

### Using powershell

You can use powershell only if you installed your GitLab Runner on Windows. You can't use anything else in that case.